# Usage of Blenc extension of Apache

Tags: php, apache, encryption, php-extension, blenc

I'm a bit confused while using Blenc v1.1.4b in Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 with PHP 5.3.10. From a tutorial online, I have to encrypt my PHP scripts using key file. I use the following commands to encrypt PHP scripts:

```
export BLENCODE='php -f /path/to/blenc-1.1.4b/tools/blencode.php'
$BLENCODE plain.php
```

The script will:

1. create a 32-character blowfish unencrypted key
2. create a 44-character redistributable key file in the same directory, named `key_file.blenc`
3. create a backup directory to save the original `plain.php`
4. convert `plain.php` to an encrypted version `plain.phpenc`
5. create a symlink named as `plain.php` and link to `plain.phpenc`

it returns:

> Fatal error: blenc_compile: Validation of script '/path/to/plain.php' failed, cannot execute. in Unknown on line 0

seems failed. Then I copy the contents of `key_file.blenc` to `/usr/local/etc/blenckeys` by (assume I have rights to write the file):

```
cat key_file.blenc > /usr/local/etc/blenckeys
```

reload the browser, still fails. Then I create a `.htaccess` to define where the key is:

```
php_value blenc.keyfile /usr/local/blenc/blenckeys
```

reload the browser again. Success! The PHP page finally starts to load. For other pages, I repeat the command, such as:

```
$BLENCODE second_page.php
cat key_file.blenc > /usr/local/etc/blenckeys
```

Last, remove or move the `backup` directory and the `key_file.blenc`.

My questions are:

1. Do I have to save the blowfish unencrypted key?
2. How can I do this in batch and encrypt files once they are updated (i.e. how to manage files while using Blenc)?
3. Should I do in my local computer or should I run it at web server?
4. Since Blenc does not require `<?php` and `?>` and removing the tags are quite troublesome, any workarounds that Blenc can support PHP tags?